# "No component factory found for" Error When trying to push from one Page to another

Tags: angular, ionic2

I get an error when trying to push from one page to another. When I try to push  to same page, it won't give that error. Only i get error when pushing from one page to another. 'setRoot()' also not giving an error.

```
this.navCtrl.push( Page7 );
```

I have added the Page7 to app.module.ts.

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { Page1 } from '../pages/page1/page1';
import { Page2 } from '../pages/page2/page2';
import { Page3 } from '../pages/page3/page3';
import { Page4 } from '../pages/page4/page4';
import { Page5 } from '../pages/page5/page5';
import { Page6 } from '../pages/page6/page6';
import { Page7 } from '../pages/page7/page7';

@NgModule({
declarations: [
MyApp,
Page1,
Page2,
Page3,
Page4,
Page5,
Page6,
Page7
],
imports: [
IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
],
bootstrap: [IonicApp],
entryComponents: [
MyApp,
Page1,
Page2,
Page3,
Page4,
Page5,
Page6,
Page7
],
providers: []
})

export class AppModule {}
```

This is a ionic 2 Application. It Gives this error.

```
EXCEPTION: Error in ./Page6 class Page6 - inline template:21:56 caused by: No component factory found for Page7
```

[console error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAcQo.png)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I found the solution. You have to add the page that you are trying to push, to the parent directory. That should also be included in to the @NgModule also.

```
import {ApiServices} from '../../providers/api-services';
import { Visualizer } from '../Page7/Page7';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-page6',
  templateUrl: 'page6.html',
  providers: [ ApiServices ],
  entryComponents:[ Page7 ]
})

export class Page6 {
    tapped(event, id ) {
      this.navCtrl.push( Page7,{
       id: id
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: To be more specific, you have to add your page to the "entryComponents" list. Doesn't matter if you do this with the "entryComponents"-Property of the Component-decorator or within the NgModule-Decorator related "entryComponents"-Property. All pages have to appear somehow within this list. Otherwise angular doesn't create a factory for this component. The Ionic-Docs / Angular-Docs aren't really clear about that. It also doesn't matter were you put your source code, but the upper case indeed does play a role when it comes to angulars ahead of time (AoT) compilation. Be careful about that.

Comment: Ionic 2.0.0 this issue is fixed.

Answer (score 18):

Have you put your component in `exports[]` in its `@NgModule`? or `entryComponents`?

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MaterialModule.forRoot(),
    ],
    exports: [
        ConfirmDialog,
    ],
    declarations: [
        ConfirmDialog,
    ],
    providers: [
        DialogsService,
    ],
    entryComponents: [
        ConfirmDialog,
    ],
```

Comment: Looks like your code is incomplete, isn't it? Also, you provide the code after asking a question, so it's not really clear what exactly the code you provided does. Please clarify.

Comment: I put it on ngModule. No need to put on exports. Only need to put on declerations and entry components.

Comment: Yes, this process worked in my case too. There are 3 places where the component should be mentioned: 1. While importing the component then, 2. Adding in 'declerations' and 3. add in entryComponents in @NgModule. That's it.

Answer (score 4):

You can do something like this.

After importing or creating **home.module.ts** with followings,

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from './home';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HomePage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(HomePage),
  ],
})
export class HomePageModule {}
```

Remove all import page links. For example,

```
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
```

Then, replace page links like,

*rootPage: any = HomePage;*
with **rootPage: any = 'HomePage';**

Or,

*this.navCtrl.push(HomePage);* with **this.navCtrl.push('HomePage');**

i.e. write class name within single or double quotes.

Comment: `rootPage: any = HomePage; with rootPage: any = 'HomePage';` - i could have saved some hair if i had not missed the quotes around the page name

Answer (score 3):

You may want to didn't put it in quotes:

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create("SearchPage")
```

instead of (incorrect):

```
let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(SearchPage)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the error could be the UpperCase letter in your path when you import, that's work for me.