# Typescript error - The Angular AoT build failed - Node.js + Ionic mobile app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I'm trying to create an Android app (Node.js + Ionic) that shows random text and pictures (the selection of texts and pictures are stored in arrays). I'm trying to install this app on my phone. The app works in Chrome.

When I give the ionic serve command in the command prompt, it works perfectly in Chrome, Random1 gives a random text and a random picture every time I push the next button, Random2 only gives a random picture every time I push the next button. 
When I give the "ionic cordova run android --prod --release" command in the command prompt, I get this error:

```js
[16:54:50]  build prod started ...
[16:54:50]  clean started ...
[16:54:50]  clean finished in 6 ms
[16:54:50]  copy started ...
[16:54:50]  deeplinks started ...
[16:54:50]  deeplinks finished in 84 ms
[16:54:50]  ngc started ...
[16:55:02]  typescript error
            Type Random1Page in
            C:/.../pages/random1/random1.ts is part of the declarations of 2 modules: AppModule in
            C:/.../app/app.module.ts and
            Random1PageModule in
            C:/.../pages/random1/random1.module.ts!
            Please consider moving Random1Page in
            C:/.../pages/random1/random1.ts to a higher module that imports AppModule in
            C:/.../app/app.module.ts and Random1PageModule in
            C:/.../pages/random1/random1.module.ts. You
            can also create a new NgModule that exports and includes Random1Pag
e in C:/.../pages/random1/random1.ts then import that NgModule in AppModule in
            C:/.../app/app.module.ts and
            Random1PageModule in
            C:/.../pages/random1/random1.module.ts.
Typescript error - Error: The Angular AoT build failed. See the issues above
    at C:/...\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:237:55
    at step (C:/...\no
de_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:32:23)
    at Object.next (C:/...\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:13:53)
    at fulfilled (C:/...\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\aot\aot-compiler.js:4:58)
    at anonymous
```

I gave this command from the folder of the ionic app. This folder contains these folders:

[image]

Is this the right folder to give this command?

random1.ts:

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Random2Page } from '../random2/random2';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-random1',
  templateUrl: 'random1.html',
})
export class Random1Page {
  random1_arr: string[]= ["text1", "text2", "text3"];
  random1_act: string;
  image_arr: string[]= ["../assets/imgs/Pic1.jpg", "../assets/imgs/Pic2.jpg"];
  image_act: string;
  person_arr: string[]= ["person1", "person2"];
  person_act: string;
  person_not_act: string;
  counter= 0;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
    this.image_act= '';
    let random_index= Math.floor(Math.random() * 2);
    this.person_act= this.person_arr[random_index];
    this.person_not_act= this.person_arr[random_index? 0: 1];
    this.GenerateRandom1PicturePerson();
  }

  GenerateRandom1PicturePerson() {
    this.random1_act= this.random1_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.random1_arr.length)];
    this.image_act= this.image_arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.image_arr.length)];
    this.person_act= [this.person_not_act, this.person_not_act= this.person_act][0];
    this.counter++;

    if(this.counter >= 7) {
      this.navCtrl.push(Random2Page);
    }
  }
}
```

app.module.ts:

```js
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { ListPage } from '../pages/list/list';
import { Random1Page } from '../pages/random1/random1';
import { Random2Page } from '../pages/random2/random2';
import { LoggedinPage } from '../pages/loggedin/loggedin';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    Random1Page,
    Random2Page,
    LoggedinPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage,
    ListPage,
    Random1Page,
    Random2Page,
    LoggedinPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From your question, we can't be sure if you **want** to use Lazy-loaded pages or not. If you do want to use lazy-loaded pages (doing this will increase the performance of the app) then the following steps will help you fixing the issue.

If you don't want to use lazy-loaded pages in your app, check @Sampath's answer instead.

---

When you add `@IonicPage()` on top of any of your pages:

```
@IonicPage() // <-- Here!
@Component({
  selector: 'page-random1',
  templateUrl: 'random1.html',
})
export class Random1Page { ... }
```

means that it would be lazy loaded. You also should have a `random1.module.ts` file in the same directory of that page, like this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { Random1Page } from './random1';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    Random1Page,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(Random1Page),
  ],
})
export class Random1PageModule {}
```

As you can see in that last file, **`Random1Page` is part of the `Random1PageModule` module**.

Now getting back to the error you're getting:

> typescript error
>   Type **Random1Page** in
>   C:/.../pages/random1/random1.ts **is part of the declarations of 2 modules**: **AppModule** in
>   C:/.../app/app.module.ts **and**
>   **Random1PageModule** in
>   C:/.../pages/random1/random1.module.ts!

So in order to fix it, you would need to remove that page (and every other lazy-loaded page) from the `AppModule` located in the `app.module.ts` file:

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';

import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp
    // HomePage,
    // ListPage,
    // Random1Page, <-- Remove it from here
    // Random2Page,
    // LoggedinPage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp),
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp
    // HomePage,
    // ListPage,
    // Random1Page, <-- And also from here
    // Random2Page,
    // LoggedinPage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

You can find more information about lazy-loading in the Ionic blog:

- **[Ionic and Lazy Loading Pt 1](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/)**
- **[Ionic and Lazy Loading Pt 2](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-2/)**

Comment: Hope this is too hot for the OP no? :) It seems OP doesn't use lazy loading at all on OP's project.

Comment: @Sampath Oh, I'm not sure of that since in the screenshot of the project we can't see the files inside of each page's folder. But yes, I'll edit my answer to let the user know that my answer is valid **only if the user wants to use lazy loaded pages** in his/her app.

Comment: Yes, You can see that huge list of pages has been declared on the `app.module.ts`. That means this must be an old project or not using lazy loading at all.

Comment: Yeah, or maybe it was just a mistake from the user, not being aware of what lazy-loading is or how it should be used in Ionic. Some users are following old tutorials where it's said that each page should be added to the app module, but that's not valid anymore when using lazy-loading :/

Comment: Thank you for the long answer! I haven't heard of the Lazy Loading, however I'd like to use it. I already have random1.module.ts and random2.module.ts files. I deleted the lines you recommended from app.module.ts, but now I get an error when giving ionic serve command: "Uncaught error: No component factory found for LoggedinPage. Did you add it to @NgMdule.entryComponents?" I got the same error for Random1Page and Random2Page when I added LoggedinPage to the entryComponents.

Comment: Hi `Sebaferreras`, I have deleted my answer since OP downvoted it. Please edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @Sampath it was not the OP's owner who downvoted your question and mine as well (you can check the history of her reputation and you won't find our downvotes). So seems like there's someone downvoting some answers for no reason :(

Comment: @Tio is this a public repo that I can take a look to see what should be done in order to fix it?

Comment: OK, It seems I'm getting series of downvotes for my questions as well as answers :(

Comment: Anyway, I have undeleted my answer. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: @sebaferreras No, it's not public, but I can add copy of the files here. It still doesn't work. The pages which are not listed amongst entryComponents don't load (on my mobile). Nothing happens when I click the button, that usually loads them. Could you help me? Which code shall I copy into my original question? Which file would you like to see?

Comment: Please take a look at the links I've added at the end of my answer. One of the things that you should check is that if you use lazy-load, you don't need to import the pages, but use their name as a string (this is explained in those links). So if you want to push the `Random1Page`, don't use `this.navCtrl.push(Random1Page)` as a class, but as a string like this: `this.navCtrl.push('Random1Page')` (also remove the `import` statement from the files where the page is used)

Comment: Thanks, it works this way :) The only problem is that the pictures don't load now :S I guess this problem is caused by something else...

Comment: Glad to hear that @Tio :)

Comment: I still had issues when using navigation. This seems to solve it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43301030/4469947.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have used latest CLI `ionic generate page Random1Page`, it creates a lazy loaded module for you. That is `Random1PageModule`. It seems you're **not using lazy loading** on your app. So delete that module.i.e. `Random1PageModule` under your page's folder.

Hereafter when you create a page you can use this `CLI` if you don't need to use Lazy loading pages.

`ionic generate page Random1Page --no-module`

***Note:*** I highly suggest you to use Lazy loading. It'll give huge performance boost to your app.

Here you can read more about [**lazy loading**](https://blog.ionicframework.com/ionic-and-lazy-loading-pt-1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try below command:

```
npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev
```

And it worked.

**Also if not working then** try to downgrade the app-script dependency in package.json as below:

From

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.4"
```

to

```
"@ionic/app-scripts": "3.2.3"
```